# Use of prepositions with verbs

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

Is there a resource, a dictionary perhaps, that gives the appropriate preposition to use with a verb - an alphabetized list of verbs with corresponding prepositions and example sentences?

Comment: There are several books on that. Try the Oxford University Press online, Longman, or any other major publishing co. I'm sure you'll find some.

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because it is a request for resources